# Find minimum non zero value in dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, min

I have a dictionary and I would like to get the key whose value is the minimum nonzero.

E.g. given the input:

```
{1:0, 2:1, 3:2}
```

It would return 2.

Comment: What have you already tried? You should post what you've attempted.

Comment: I have tried to get the key with: min(diction.items(), key = lambda x:x[1] if x>0) but I get the error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 6):

You can do it on **one** iteration.

```
d = {1:0, 2:1, 3:2}

# Save the minimum value and the key that belongs to it as we go
min_val = None
result = None
for k, v in d.items():
    if v and (min_val is None or v < min_val):
        min_val = v
        result = k

print(result)
```

Some assumptions:

- Negative values will be considered
- It will return the **first key** that found
- If it helps, `min_val` will hold the minimum value

Answer (score 4):

You can use the fact `0` is considered `False` to filter out `0` values. Then use `next` with a generator expression:

```
d = {1:0, 2:1, 3:2}

val = min(filter(None, d.values()))
res = next(k for k, v in d.items() if v == val)  # 2
```

This will only return *one* key in the case of duplicate keys with `1` as value. For multiple matches, you can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == val]
```

Note your *literal* ask for "minimum non-zero" will *include* negative values.

**Performance note**

The above solution is 2-pass but has time complexity O(*n*), it's not possible to have *lower* complexity than this. A 1-pass O(*n*) solution is possible as shown by @Maor, but this isn't necessarily more efficient:

```
# Python 3.6.0

%timeit jpp(d)  # 43.9 ms per loop
%timeit mao(d)  # 98.8 ms per loop
%timeit jon(d)  # 183 ms per loop
%timeit reu(d)  # 303 ms per loop
```

Code used for benchmarking:

```
from random import randint

n = 10**6
d = {i: randint(0, 9) for i in range(n)}

def jpp(d):
    val = min(filter(None, d.values()))
    return next(k for k, v in d.items() if v == val)

def mao(d):
    min_val = None
    result = None
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v and (min_val is None or v < min_val):
            min_val = v
            result = k
    return result

def jon(d):
    return min({i for i in d if d[i] != 0})

def reu(d):
    no_zeros = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != 0}
    key, val = min(no_zeros.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
    return key
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `dict` is named `a`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = {1:0, 2:1, 3:2}
# remove zeros
no_zeros = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if v != 0} # can use `if v`
# find minimal key and value (by value)
key, val = min(no_zeros.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
# key = 2, val = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(min(i for i in dictionary if  dictionary[i] != 0))
```

this makes a set with no zeros and return the minimum value in that set. Though it is worth pointing out this makes 2 iterations and is thus slower than Maor Refaeli's solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
some_dict = {1:0, 2:1, 3:2}
compare = []

for k, v in some_dict.items():
    if k != 0:
        compare.append(k)

x = min(compare)

print(x)
```

I just `appended` all the non-zero `keys` to a `list` (`compare`) and then applied `min(compare)`

We can plug `x` back in and check that it is pointing to the key `1` which is the smallest non-zero `key` and that returns it's `value` which is `0`

```
>>> print(some_dict[x]) 
>>> 0
```